# How to change the IMEI number of a rooted android device via appium or adb?

Tags: java, android, adb, appium, appium-android

I want to change the IMEI of a rooted Android device via adb so that the entire process could be automated via appium. Is there any way I could do that  using appium. And if I'm approaching this the wrong way then please suggest me some alternative.

Edit: There are various ways to change it. I've googled it and found many results. But I need to change it via appium (i.e. I need to automate it).

Comment: just google it ... found various ways to do it

Comment: Why do you need to change the IMEI? Have you taken a look at https://usmile.at/blog/how-to-change-imei-on-android-devices

Comment: @snnguyen I've already looked into the article, but I need to automate the entire process via appium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPOSED IMEI Changer or Xposed installer , if your phone rooted

http://bayanbox.ir/download/3977373319269557846/mebile.ir-XPOSED-IMEI-Changer-Pro.1.3.apk